# Why GHC avoids tacit programming?

Tags: haskell, tacit-programming

I was looking at [`GHC.Unicode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.1.0/docs/src/GHC-Unicode.html) library source and realized that almost all the Haskell internal libraries avoid tacit programming (aka point-free style) most of the time. Simple functions can be easily converted, such as:

```
isLatin1 :: Char -> Bool
isLatin1 c = c <= '\xff'
```

Resulting in:

```
isLatin1 :: Char -> Bool
isLatin1 = (<= '\xff')
```

But there are cases where I can't apply it, such as when I have more complex functions, like:

```
isOctDigit c =  c >= '0' && c <= '7'
```

Is hard to deduct a way to compose the operations. I don't mean to get in the range, I mean to do multiple operations just by composing functions. The following:

```
isOctDigit = (>= '0') && (<= '7')
```

Is not valid, and also `(>= '0') . (<= '7')` **clearly** cannot happen because of the different return types.

Taking account these observations, I have the following questions:

- **When should I use point-free programming instead of explicit it all?**
- **Why GHC prefer to explicit instead of use partial functions?**
- **How can I compose two functions of different types without being explicit, such as in the example?**

Comment: FYI `liftA2 (&&) (>= '0') (<= '7')` is one way to do your example.

Comment: That’s quite a few question to be put in, well, one question.

Comment: This is not really a complete answer, but... I have worked on a few codebases that were meticulous about using the simplest, most obvious looking code everywhere. I found myself pleasantly nimble in modifying them.

Comment: The first two questions are more on-topic on [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://programmers.stackexchange.com). It's largely a stylistic issue: just pick whatever expresses your particular problem the clearest.

Comment: Tacit programming is not a goal per se; it's only a useful tool... when it's useful — there are some cases in which a tacit (point-free) definition is significantly more human readable; there are, however, cases where it's immensely less readable than non-tacit.

Comment: @Rufflewind - The first question posed is off-topic at Programmers.  Ultimately, it boils down to a poll-by-example which is a poor fit for the StackExchange Q&A format.  The second question is marginally on-topic but would certainly need some backing research to make it a more interesting and constructive question.  And to round out the trifecta, the third question is obviously off-topic for Programmers as it's focused upon implementation only.